# Assistance on possible incorrect logic in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I'm really trying to understand the issue I am having as it is not making any sense to me. For testing purposes I created a very simple 2010 InfoPath form published to a Form Library with only one control (Option Button) with a field name "Yes No Field" below:

[image]

I also created a List Workflow attached to the same Form Library with logic shown below:

[image]

The expectation is when I click Add document in the Form Library, select "Yes" on the form previously shown and click Submit, the addition of a new form should populate the Form Library. In addition, it will fill in the column Yes No Field with my "Yes" selection from the form and in turn trigger the Workflow shown below:

[image]

Per the "Start Approval Process" in the Workflow logic, the Workflow will then send 2 emails stating that *an approval has started on the new item* and that *a Task was assigned by the user who added a new document*.

As for the "If Current Item:Yes No Field", the expectation is that if the user selects "Yes" on the form, a separate email should be sent out to Test@testing.com. I have tested and the only thing that gets sent out are the 2 emails where it details that an approval has started and that a Task was assigned by the user who added the new document.

Regardless of selecting "Yes" the user with email address Test@testing.com **NEVER** receives the email even when the condition is satisfied. What am I doing wrong in the Workflow? To me, the logic makes perfect sense and very understandable but apparently it is wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon testing the other night I found that using a parallel block and adding the Approval statement plus the if condition worked wonders. Not sure why I didn't think of it but it solves my issue as it fires at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the workflow internal status to see if it has thrown any errors? If there are no errors, I recommend that you either place your "if" block before the approval process or add another condition to the if block such as "if Yes No field equal yes And outcome equals approved/rejected". It's possible that your workflow is stuck at the approval stage as it's not instructed what to do after the document is approved/rejected so the workflow status may not be updated.

Comment: Thank swat. I actually figured it out last night through testing. My solution was, and I don't know why I didn't think of it, was to use a parallel block with the Approval and the condition statement to fire off at the same time. It works as expected.